# Going back in time in Kafka using offset

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Is there a way to start a consumer from a specific offset using the initial properties that we pass

I know there is props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest") but that gets me to the beginning.

However I want to go back and my scenarios are as follows

1. Specify an offset where I want to start at
2. Specify the time where I want to start

And I want to do that using the initial properties as a preferred option.
If that is not possible then using some other mechanism

Attaching my Simple Consumer code for reference

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

public class SimpleConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String topicName = "test3";
        Properties props = new Properties();

        String groupId = "single";

        // Kafka consumer configuration settings
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "mymachine:9092");
        props.put("group.id", groupId);
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));

        System.out.println("Starting the _NON-BATCH_ consumer ::: Topic=" + topicName+" GroupId="+groupId);

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                System.out.printf("%s   (offset:%d, key:%s, partition = %s, topic = %s)", record.value(), record.offset(), record.key(), record.partition(), record.topic());
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of kafka are you using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For scenario 1, you can use KafkaConsumer.seek(TopicPartition, offset) to specify the offset from which you read.

For scenario 2, Kafka 0.10.1.0 offers KafkaConsumer.offsetsForTimes method, allowing you to lookup the offsets for the given partitions by timestamp, then invoking seek() method to retrieve the desired messages you want.